# Tumblr Theme - Text from custom pages not showing up?

Tags: html, tumblr

I'm adapting an existing Tumblr theme and am having a few problems. When the user creates a custom page and uses the standard layout the text they put in doesn't show up anywhere on the page. I've trawled through docs and tutorials to try and find out how the text from custom pages is rendered but there doesn't appear to be any information on the topic. All I can find is a few hacky ways for displaying something only on a custom page, but I can't figure out how to get the actual text or title that the user enters. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your tumblr link?

Comment: Could you provide more information? e.g. pictures, examples, sourcecode?

Comment: @Karmacoma grigueillustration.co.uk /about is a custom layout made to look the normal layout and /links is the standard layout where I'm having problems as the text and title are not showing up